# Unable to get msbuild and powershell to play nice with parsing a path that contains spaces

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I'm trying to run a simple powershell script when a build is initiated on the build machine. From what I can tell the issue is with the path for the tfExeLocation that I'm sending as it contains spaces. I have tried a few different ways to escaping the path so that both msbuild and powershell are happy with it, but I'm missing something

The current error I get is:

```
Task "Exec" (TaskId:3)
  Task Parameter:Command="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
      "D:\Builds\23\WS\Main-SWS\Sources\Student\Main\StudentSoln\Build.ps1"
      -slnPath "D:\Builds\23\WS\Main-SWS\Sources\Student\Main\StudentSoln\"
      -tfExeLocation "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe"  (TaskId:3)
  "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
  "D:\Builds\23\WS\Main-SWS\Sources\Student\Main\StudentSoln\Build.ps1"
  -slnPath "D:\Builds\23\WS\Main-SWS\Sources\Student\Main\StudentSoln\"
  -tfExeLocation "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe"  (TaskId:3)
  The string is missing the terminator: ". (TaskId:3)
      + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx  (TaskId:3)
     ception (TaskId:3)
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString (TaskId:3)
    (TaskId:3)
Done executing task "Exec". (TaskId:3)
```

This is the call from the target in my project file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PowerShellExe Condition="'$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">$(WINDIR)\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</PowerShellExe>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PowerShellExe)&quot; &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build.ps1&quot; -slnPath &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\&quot; -tfExeLocation &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe&quot; "/>
```

Here is the Powershell script I am working with

```
Param(
    [string]$slnPath,
    [string]$tfExeLocation
    )
Push-Location "$slnPath"
write-output "Made it past push location"
& '"$tfExeLocation'" checkout *.csproj Packages.Config* /recursive
Pop-Location
```

Any help is much appreciated. I'm pretty sure it is something simple, as I have only recently started working with msbuild components and Powershell.

Comment: @PetSerAl That does not work. It gives me an error stating 'D:\Builds\23\WS\Main-SWS\Sources\Student\Main\StudentSoln\Build.ps1\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: Removing extra ``\`` character: `<Exec Command="&quot;$(PowerShellExe)&quot; &quot;&amp; '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build.ps1' -slnPath '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\' -tfExeLocation 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe'&quot;" />`

Comment: @PetSerAl Didn't notice the extra slash, so thanks for that. Tried it again with that update and got it working. Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem with quotes in your command. Simple solution would be to use single quote inside PowerShell command and put all command inside double quotes.

```
"$(PowerShellExe)" "& '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build.ps1' -slnPath '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\' -tfExeLocation 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe'"
```

After proper XML escaping that would become:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PowerShellExe)&quot; &quot;&amp; '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build.ps1' -slnPath '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\' -tfExeLocation 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe'&quot;" />
```